# Find word frequency with respect to word occurrence in documents

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to number of documents where a particular word occurs

Example:

```
data = ["This is my pen","That is his pen","This is not my pen"]
```

desired output:

```
{'This':2,'is': 3,'my': 2,'pen':3}
{'That':1,'is': 3,'his': 1,'pen':3}
{'This':2,'is': 3,'not': 1,'my': 2,'pen':3}

for sent in documents:
    for word in sent.split():

    if word in sent:

        windoc=dict(Counter(sent.split()))
        print(windoc)
```

Comment: Is this a valid output? : `{'This':2, 'not': 1, 'my': 2, 'pen':3, 'is':3}` -- `{'This':2,'my': 2,'pen':3, 'is': 3}` -- `{'That':1,'his': 1,'pen':3, 'is': 3}
`

Comment: Yes, 'This' appears in two documents so 2 and so on for other words

Comment: Would it be OK if I dropped the dict and created lists instead? : `['This', 'not', 'my', 'pen', 'is']` -- `['This', 'my', 'pen', 'is']` -- `['That', 'his', 'pen', 'is']`

Comment: it should be fine @AK47

Comment: how about if a word occurs twice in a document? should it be counted twice? for instance, should the output above be the same if you have this input: `data = ["This is my pen my pen my pen","That is his pen","This is not my pen"]`

Comment: @olivecoder No it shouldn't be counted twice if it's within the same document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that a word shall not be counted more than once per document:

```
import collections

data = ["This is my pen my pen my pen","That is his pen","This is not my pen"]
deduped = (set(d.split()) for d in data)
freq =  collections.Counter(w for d in deduped for w in d)
result = [{ w: freq[w] for w in d } for d in deduped ]
```

You need to deduplicate the words first (see `deduped` above). I made deduped a generator to avoid having an intermediate list sets, but that is going to produce an intermediate set of words for each document anyway.

Alternatively, you could implement your own counter. Implementing your own counter isn't a good idea in general but may be required if memory consumption is critical and you want to avoid the intermediate sets created when iterating over the `deduped` generator.

Either way, the time and memory complexity are linear.

Output:

```
[{'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'my': 2, 'pen': 3},
 {'That': 1, 'his': 1, 'is': 3, 'pen': 3},
 {'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'my': 2, 'not': 1, 'pen': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a dictionary to hold the `words frequency` based on all the available sentences. Then construct the desired output. Here's a working example:

Given the input documents:

```
In [1]: documents 
Out[1]: ['This is my pen', 'That is his pen', 'This is not my pen']
```

Construct the words frequency dictionary:

```
In [2]: d = {}
    ...: for sent in documents:
    ...:     for word in set(sent.split()):    
    ...:         d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
    ...:
```

Then construct the desired output:

```
In [3]: result = []
    ...: for sent in documents:
    ...:     result.append({word: d[word] for word in sent.split()})
    ...:     

In [4]: result 
Out[4]: 
[{'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'my': 2, 'pen': 3},
 {'That': 1, 'his': 1, 'is': 3, 'pen': 3},
 {'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'my': 2, 'not': 1, 'pen': 3}]
```

---

So, overall, the code looks like this:

```
documents = ['This is my pen', 'That is his pen', 'This is not my pen']
d = {}
# construct the words frequencies dictionary
for sent in documents:
    for word in set(sent.split()):    
        d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1

# format the output in the desired format
result = []
for sent in documents:
    result.append({word: d[word] for word in sent.split()})
```

Comment: word shouldn't be counted twice if it's within the same document

Comment: @rookie the only difference would be to apply set on the result of document split `set(sent.split())` which will keep the unique words of each document. Everything remains the same. I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["This is my pen is is","That is his pen pen pen pen","This is not my pen"]

d = []
for s in data:
    for word in set(s.split()):
        d.append(word)

wordCount = Counter(d)
for item in data:
    result = {}
    for word in item.split():
        result[word] = wordCount[word]
    print (result)
```

output:

```
{'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'my': 2, 'pen': 3}
{'That': 1, 'is': 3, 'his': 1, 'pen': 3}
{'This': 2, 'is': 3, 'not': 1, 'my': 2, 'pen': 3}
```

Comment: This has a problem.  if the a particular word repeats in a sentence/doc ,even that is getting counted. For example in first doc if I change it to "This is is my pen" --> 'is' is counted as 4 where as it should remain only 3 as word occurrences is with respect to number of docs it's appearing.